# Set Text based on list item click

Tags: android, android-listview

I am having a layout consisting of ListView and a label. Look at the image below.

[image]

I implemented listview using base adapter in a seperate .java file.
Could anyone suggest me how can i set text to the label on click of list item?

EDITED :

The text of the label should be number of list items clicked.
Suppose i clicked a **button in a** list item, the label should be set to 1.
Similarly in the next attempt if i clicked another **list item's button** it should be set to 2 and so.. on..

Comment: are you trying to set the label to whatever text the clicked list item has?

Comment: no. I am having different logic to set text for the label.

Comment: What have you tried and where is your problem exactly? Are you using OnItemClickListener or buttons in each convertView?

Comment: I am using onclick event for buttons in convertview and not onitemclicklistener.
I am not getting any idea on how to do this one because customadapter logic (convert view's logic) is in one file and the label is in an activity which is in another file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sir,

What you are saying is this, you have your adapter in one class and the activity in another file. Well you could do this, to update the textview.

pass the context to the activity, and if its in the adapter you are maintaining the count then once the count has been updated,

then, assume you have this method in the activity

```
public void updateTextView(int count) {
    // enter your code here to set the count in the textview
}
```

and from the baseAdapter call the above method like this:

```
if(mContext != null) {
    ((YourActivity)mContext).updateTextView(mCount);
}
```

and the textview in the activity will be updated!
I hope it helps.

Comment: Hey i am getting compile time error saying GridActivity cannot be resolved into a type when i tried ((GridActivity)cont).updateValueTextView(1); . Are you sure we can call updateValueTextView() of activity in this way?

Comment: Yes i am sure. Make sure you are passing the context to the adapter as this instead of the activity.

Comment: @G_S Dhara's comment is incorrect (her answer is correct though). You _have_ to pass the adapter `this` or `GridActivity.this`. Passing context using `getBaseContext()` or `getApplicationContext()` will not work because you need to up-cast `mContext` to `GridActivity` in order to call `GridActivity#updateValueTextView()`. The error you're seeing isn't because of this. You should figure out why your IDE cannot resolve `GridActivity`. Try using the fully-qualified class name.....

Comment: @G_S ..... I understand that keeping adapters separate from the activity is recommended. But, if you were to include the adapter (GridActivity) as an inner class to your activity, you could access `updateValueTextView()` directly, without going through the Context/Activity.

Comment: If GridActivity is your adapter then in that case, the Context/activity thing won't work, it needs to be an activity. And yes, placing them in the same file will work too but it would just congest the code. :)

Comment: Perfect. +1 for helping me a lot. This solution worked for me now. I didnt see the compile time error again today. Thanks a lot Dhara Shah and user2558882 for suggesting me this :)

Answer (score 2):

In your `OnItemClickListener` call `adapter.getItem(int position)` to retrieve the object from the collection backing your `BaseAdapter`. From there, you should be able to retrieve any fields you need.

**Edit:**

Your edit clears up the question. Updated answer:

```
private int mCounter = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // ListView listView = getYourListView();
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            mCounter++;
            updateTextView();
        }
    });

    if(savedInstanceState != null) {
        mCounter = savedInstanceState.getInt("counter", 0);
    }

    updateTextView();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putInt("counter", mCounter);
}

private void updateTextView() {
    // TextView textView = getYourTextView();
    textView.setText(String.valueOf(mCounter));
}
```

Comment: my custom adapter code is in one file and the actual activity is in another. Do you think using the textview ( which is in my activity) will be accessible in my custom adapter?

Comment: You should keep a reference to your adapter in your `Activity` as a member variable. This way, in `onItemClick`, you can simply call something like `mAdapter.getItem(position)`. This will return the object that is at the given position in the dataset backing your adapter (this is typically an ArrayList).

Comment: Well if that's the answer... let me add some more info to the question as this would not clear up my doubt.
Sorry for continuous edits to question. Your updated question is perfectly ok and thanks for letting me know new way of writing this thing. But can you once again see my updated question please

Comment: I give up. Your question keeps changing and is unclear. Sorry, I tried.

Comment: Unclear? Can You say what you didnt understand so that i can clear it for you

Answer (score 1):

Just `OnItemClickListener` in your `ListView` then in the `onClick` you will get a value `arg2` which is the `position` of the item which is clicked.

Just get that value from the `ArrayList` from which you are displaying the `ListView` and show it...

Hope this is what you need if I have not misunderstood your question.

Comment: Duplicate of my answer.

Comment: Dude I don't think so.There is a huge difference between your and my explanation and I don't think that I have used adapter.getItem(int position) anywhere in my explanation.

Comment: "Just get that value from the ArrayList from which you are displaying the ListView and show it" -- calling `getItem(int)` on the adapter is the proper way to do this.

Comment: I can't see any duplication here.

Comment: that can be a better method but it wasnt duplication as I dint write anythng you wrote here.

Comment: If you're maintaining 2 different objects for your data, you're doing it wrong. Period. The correct way is to use `ListView.getItemAtPosition(int position)` or `BaseAdapter.getItem(int position)`.

Comment: my custom adapter code is in one file and the actual activity is in another. Do you think using textview1( which is in my activity) will be accessible in my custom adapter?

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            String itemText=(String) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
            yourLable.setText(itemText);

        }
    });
```

Comment: my custom adapter code is in one file and the actual activity is in another. Do you think using textview1( which is in my activity) will be accessible in my custom adapter?

Answer (score 0):

In `onListItemClick` call `list.getItemAtPosition(position)` to retrieve item text

then set this text to `textview1.setText(listText)`.

Comment: Another duplicate of my answer.

Comment: my custom adapter code is in one file and the actual activity is in another. Do you think using textview1( which is in my activity) will be accessible in my custom adapter?

Comment: yes it will be accessible from other activity. Depends on what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

First Implement your onItemClickListener, where you will get int arg2 parameter, which is position, so get that position and do your stuff whatever you want like below.

```
 list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {

                LABLE.setText(""+arg2);

            }
        });
```

Comment: I am using a class which extends baseadapter and overriding getView().
In the getview() i am having a button to which, I am handling onclick event.
And the label is in the activity. I dont think the label will be accessible in the custom adapter class.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code

```
public class ListA extends ListActivity {
 private TextView selection;
private static final String[] items={"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"};
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
super.onCreate(icicle);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                items));
selection=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.selection);
}
@Override
 public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position,
                            long id) {
selection.setText(position);
}
}
```

Comment: I am having my entire logic in a customadapter Ameer. It will be hard for me to change back to listactivity